# how to migrate away from ConfigurationManager in .net 6

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I am trying to migrate a legacy .net framework project to .net 6

One problem is that we have a Constants class, which contains code like this:

```
public static class Constants
{
   public static int MaxCodes = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxCodes"] ?? "250");
}
```

How can I move this to .net 6? I don't think IConfiguration is Injectable in a static class, so need to change this class to a non-static one and using `services.AddSingleton`.

But it means lots of code changes in the referenced code. Are there other ways to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there other ways to do it?

You can stick with the static class and pass the dependencies to a custom `Initialize` method, which you call on bootstrap.

```
public static class Constants
{
    private static bool _isInitialized;

    static Constants()
    {
        _isInitialized = false;
    }

    static void Initialize(IConfiguration configurationManager)
    {
        if (!_isInitialized)
        {
            MaxCodes = Convert.ToInt32(configurationManager.AppSettings["MaxCodes"] ?? "250");
            _isInitialized = true;
        }
    }

    public static int MaxCodes { get; private set; }
}
```

The `_isInitialized` flag and private setters ensure the state can no longer be changed *after* bootstrap.